# vi -- replace chars from part of line

Tags: sed, vi, command-substitution

I've got a file with all Belgian cities. Some of these cities have boroughs.

```
Lier;stad;Antwerpen;49,70;33930;Lier;Koningshooikt
Knokke-Heist;gem.;WestVlaanderen;56,44;33825;Knokke;Westkapelle;Heist;Ramskapelle
```

But I want to divide the boroughs with `, and space` instead of `;`. So I want to get this:

```
Lier;stad;Antwerpen;49,70;33930;Lier, Koningshooikt
Knokke-Heist;gem.;West-Vlaanderen;56,44;33825;Knokke, Westkapelle, Heist, Ramskapelle
```

I use `vi` regularly but this kind of substitution is hard for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do (assuming GNU `sed`):

```
:%!sed 's/;/, /6g'
```

To replace the 6th to last `;` with `,`.

With `vim` using look-behind operators:

```
:%s/\v((;.*){5})@<=;/, /g
```

(that is replace the `;`s that are preceded by at least 5 `;`s).

Comment: It seems to work but what should I add so it would start from the 6th and go on instead change only the 6th? EDIT: the g of course :). THanks

Answer (score 1):

Another way in `vim`:

```
:g/^/call feedkeys("nnnnna") | s/;/, /gc
```

The `feedkeys()` function use the string `nnnnna` as if we typed them on keyboard, `s`ubstitution with `gc` flags tell `vim` to substitute all occurrences with confirmation from user.

Here we simply ignored first 5 occurrences by `nnnnn`, then an `a` confirm all others.

The `g/^/` made this command applied for all lines.